# which means Undefined index: team_id in Laravel

Tags: laravel, undefined

I am in the process of changing the registration process. When the user is invited, the user is assigned to the same team. And if he registers himself, he can choose a team.

Everything works, except with the team_id. I always get the error message:

```
Undefined index: team_id
```

What does the error message mean? How can I fix the error?

I do not understand why this does not work, because the same function works with the avatar.

Function:

```
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:30',
        'username' => 'required|string|max:20|alpha_num|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        'birthday' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:-16 years',
        'agb' => 'accepted',
        'gender' => 'required|boolean',
        'team_id' => 'numeric'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    if($data['gender'])

    {
        $avatar = 'defaults\avatars\male.jpg';
    }

    else

    {
        $avatar = 'defaults\avatars\female.jpg';
    }



if($data['team_id'])
        {
            $team = $data['team_id'];
        }

        else
        {
            $team = Null;
        }


    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'team_id' => $team,
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'birthday' => $data['birthday'],
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'slug' => str_slug($data['username']),
        'avatar' => $avatar,
        'active' => false,
        'activation_token' => str_random(255)
    ]);

    Profile::create(['user_id' => $user->id ]);

    while (true) {
        $randomstring = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 0, 7);
        if (Invite::where('url','!=', $randomstring)->exists()) {
            Invite::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'url' => $randomstring
            ]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: It looks like `team_id` is not passed in your `$data` arguments of the `create` function from your view to your controller. Make sure to not forget a field named `team_id` in your blade view.

Comment: Are you reading the error? Please see [this article](https://academy.iget.com.br/en/debug-2/read-the-errors/).

Comment: `$team = $data['team_id'] ?? null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error and you will be able to understand what it means.

See this line:

```
if($data['team_id'])
```

What if the `$data` array just don't contains the `team_id` index? This code is not valid so. If you want to verify it, you must use use [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
if (array_key_exists('team_id', $key) && $data['team_id'])
```

or

```
if (isset($key['team_id']) && $data['team_id'])
```

Both are safe ways to do what you want.

Comment: what is the variable $key for this example?